# casting uint32_t to uint64_t results in different value?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, visual-c++-2015

Using Visual Studio 2015 C++, 14.0.25431.01 Update 3. I have unexpected behavior in my code. Compile and run with 64bit, Release:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int, char**) {
    for (uint32_t i = 1; i < 3; ++i) {
        uint32_t a = i * 0xfbd1e995;
        uint64_t b = a;

        std::cout << a << " 32bit" << std::endl;
        std::cout << b << " 64bit" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I expect that `a` and `b` have the same value, but when I run this I get this output:

```
4224838037 32bit
4224838037 64bit
4154708778 32bit
8449676074 64bit
```

It looks like the compiler replaces the 32bit multiplication with a 64bit multiplication. Is it allowed to do that, or is this a compiler bug? Both g++ and clang give me the numbers that I'd expect.

EDIT: I've update my code with a simpler version that has the same problem. Also, [I've just submitted a bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3125746/optimizer-uses-64bit-operation-instead-of-32bit-operation).

Comment: No repro with gcc and clang. This absolutely should not happen. Edit: Also no repro with VS on rextester.

Comment: Can't reproduce with mingw and visual studio compiler as well.

Comment: what version of VS are you using? Did you compile Release 64bit?

Comment: Same strange results witch Studio 2010 x64 Release

Comment: *"Is it allowed to do that, or is this a compiler bug?"* That would be an *extremely* serious compiler bug. Are you sure that code is really what you are running?

Comment: I could, as well, reproduce the issue, when using VS2013, and compiling in release mode.

Comment: Compiling with /O2 or /Ox results in the strange behavior, /Od or /O1 produces the expected output

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I think you should report it.

Comment: I've just filed a bug report

Comment: Only happens on Release build x64. The result is correct for Debug build, or Release build x86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this hotfix fixes the issue, at least for VS 2015:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3207317/visual-c-optimizer-fixes-for-visual-studio-2015-update-3

But it seems that VS 2008, 2010, 2013 are still affected by this bug.

Sources:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/5wwmi2/visual_studio_2015_compiler_bug_64bit_instead_of/dedfw27/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/5wwmi2/visual_studio_2015_compiler_bug_64bit_instead_of/dedzh5g/

Answer (score 7):

I could reproduce this on VS2010, and the immediate cause is this:

```
add ebx, 5BD1E995h  ; this is x
add rdi, 5BD1E995h  ; this is a 64bit version of x
```

Since it's a 64bit addition, it will just carry into the high 32 bits. This at least makes more sense than conjuring up a 64bit multiplication, it might be a corner case in induction variable elimination but that's just speculation.

Also fun is that it doesn't even save a cast by miscompiling it. The correct value is right there in `rbx`.

Comment: Why does it use `add` for a multiplication? Anyway it [doesn't seem to appear in CL19](https://godbolt.org/g/i6Y9is) anymore. I can only find `imul` with 1540483477

Comment: I think the compiler tries to be smart and replaces the loop from 0 to 50, where loop counter is multiplied by the constant, with just adding the constant.